# bitcoin public address cryptography

Tags: keys, cryptocurrency

I was learning about bitcoin cryptography and seen some strange bitcoin public addresses like this

1. 1Lets1xxxx1use1xxxxxxxxxxxy2EaMkJ
2. 1fuLL1xxxx1power1xxxxxxxxxxzatvCK
3. 1of1xxxxx1anonymity1xxxxxxxz9JzFN

how someone can derive this kind of addresses from private key? and if it is possible somehow does it gives chance to decrypt private key from public address?

Comment: For you second question, in theory this could make bruteforce search easier since you are making the key space smaller, but only by a small factor.

Answer (score 1):

You simply keep on generating private keys, derive the corresponding the public key and check whether the base58 encoded public key contains the string you're looking for. This page has more information https://github.com/JeanLucPons/VanitySearch

Answer (score 0):

They are a vanity addresses generated using the vanity key generator.

Comment: Hi Hugo and thanks for your answer. Could you maybe extend a bit more how a "vanity key generator" works with respect to cryptography?

Answer (score 0):

Address is just base58check encoded data. You can decode it, so to make such address you give string, decode it by base58, add last few characters and then encode back with base58check.